# Loop through list of dictionaries to generate single list of values

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand how to loop through a list of dictionaries to produce a single list of data.

The current format of the data:

```
data = [{'q_rounded': 100, 'title': 'Product Evaluation', 'final_score': 5.0, 'project': < Project: C > },
        {'q_rounded': 100, 'title': 'Community', 'final_score': 5.0, 'project': < Project: C > },
        {'q_rounded': 100, 'title': 'Marketing', 'final_score': 5.0, 'project': < Project: C >},
        {'q_rounded': 0, 'title': 'Product Evaluation', 'project': < Project: D > }]
```

I'm hoping to be able to end up with the final score of each title in a single list
`[project,value,value2,value3]`

I think I need to iterate through the original list using something like?

```
for item in data:
    for key,value in item.items():
        print(key,value)
```

but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding each value to a list, then inserting the title at the end:

```py
score = []

for title in data:
    x = [v for k, v in title.items() if k != "project"]
    x.insert(0, title["project"])
    score.append(x)
```

```
# Score saves in a form of
[[< Project: C >, 100, 'Product Evaluation', 5.0], ... ]
```

---

Edit

With no title:

```
x = [v for k, v in title.items() if k not in ["project", "title"]]
```

```
>>> x[0]
[< Project: C >, 100, 5.0]
```

Edit 2 (all scores)

```
all_scores = []

for title in data:
    if "final_score" in title:
        all_scores.append(title["final_score"])
```

```
>>> all_scores
[5.0, 5.0, 5.0]
```

Comment: Thanks, freddy. Is it possible to drop the `Product Evaluation` and just have the value 5? To end up with [[< Project: C >, 100, 5.0], ... ]

Comment: Yep, will edit now @JacksWastedLife

Comment: For some reason I don't get the same results as you, mine still shows the `title` very weird.
`['<Project: C>', 100, 'Product Evaluation', 5.0, '<Project: C>']`

Comment: Sorry Freddy, somehow i managed to copy and paste wrong :( . This is working. Thank you

Comment: If i wanted to collect all scores for all titles for a project within a single list, would i follow a similar approach in iterating through?

Comment: Yep, I've added an example :). If it's not quite what you want, let me know and edit your question with an example please